# What is the smallest aircraft to have a CVR / FDR?

Tags: commercial-aviation, general-aviation, flight-data-recorder, cockpit-voice-recorder

I was wondering what is the smallest aircraft to have a CVR (Cockpit Voice Recorder) and/or FDR (Flight Data Recorder)?

Small single engine prop can sometimes have the avionics, like the G1000, that records some of the flight parameters on a memory card. But what about a proper CVR or FDR?

I'm not asking about military aviation, but more about general or small commercial airplanes.

I understand that it depends of the type of operation, but what is the smallest airplane to have a CVR/FDR on board?

Comment: By "proper" CVR/FDR do you mean a unit that meets crash survivability standards? Are you asking about recorders as *required* equipment or whether they are available as an option? As to when they are required, [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1684/8730) gives answers for FAA. As far as optional equipment that doesn't have to follow all the parameters set out by regulations then you can probably install recorders on just about any aircraft.

Comment: @TomMcW Yes, it would be a unit that meets crash survivability standards but that is not necessarily required. An operator can choose to have such equipment without being legally required to. If it's required on this type of aircraft or not that's another story.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like in the [EU](https://www.easa.europa.eu/system/files/dfu/EASA-MMEL-Cessna_CE--510-00-17022014.pdf) as well as in the [US](http://fsims.faa.gov/wdocs/mmel/ce-510%20r1.pdf) the [Cessna CE-510 Mustang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cessna_Citation_Mustang) needs one according to the minimum equipment list.

In the EU

> -70-01
>
> *** Cockpit Voice Recorder (For Combined Voice Data Recorder, refer to 31-30-01)

And in the US

> -30-01
>
> *** Flight Data Recorder (FDR) System

That is a 6 seat plane, you will be hard pressed to find something smaller although other similar in class aircraft may also have them.

It looks like some versions of the Cirrus SR-22 include an [Aircraft Data Logger](http://servicecenters.cirrusdesign.com/techpubs/pdf/AMM/SR22/pdf/31-30.pdf) but im not sure if that conforms to the various impact regulations for a black box.